# What are some uses of part 93589?

Tags: piece-information, annual-support

I discovered that part 93589:

[image: 93589]

Was used in the Creator set Extreme Engines (31072):

[image: 31072-1 Extreme Engines]

This element strikes me as the sort of part-out-of-other-parts that was created to serve a single purpose: the front end on specific race cars. For most cases, it seems like the 4x1 slope curved can do the job quite well minus the slight curve at the front:

[image: Slope Curved 4x1]

The element only gets used in the main model. What are some other uses for this part? Why was it created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part was introduced for licensed polybags in the Racers Ferrarri line (30195 and 30190):

[image: 30195]

[image: 30190]

It has been used that way a few other times since then, but it has also been used a few other ways in released sets.

It was used in 95012-1 BARC Speeder with Sidecar to round out the back end of the CIS speeder nicely:

[image: 75012]

And identically in 75017-1 Duel on Geonosis:

[image: 75017]

The part was also used to create a nice nose for a dragon in 70736-1 Attack of the Morro Dragon:

[image: 70736]

It has also been used in a couple different City sets to round off aircraft components such as the engines on 4209-1 Fire Plane:

[image: 4209-1]

And the top of the Helicopter in 60010 Fire Helicopter:

[image: 60010-2]

This part has only appeared in about a dozen sets in six different colors. It's fun to have another shape to play with in models, and this part adds some unique possibilities to possible builds.